# Why does the homotopy definition require a continuous function?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Reading Hatcher's algebraic topology book I see that a homotopy of paths in $X$ is a family of maps $f_t: I \to X$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$, such that

- $f_t(0) = x_0$ and $f_t(1) = x_1$
- The associated map $F(s, t) = f_t(s)$ is continuous

Intuitively understanding a homotopy as a continuous deformation of a path, I don't see why the stronger condition of $F$ being continuous is needed, rather than the weaker "each $f_t$ is continuous".

My question is, if there is some simple example, or maybe a theorem that I would intuitively think it holds, but fails with this weaker condition. Or any kind of justification of why the stronger condition is needed in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Each $f_t$ is continuous" merely gives yo a family of totally unrelated paths from $x_0$ to $x_1$. As a result, any two paths with same endpoints would be homotopic.  Say, if there is a "hole", you could just pick paths passing the hole somehow on the left when $t<\frac12$ and pass the hole on the right when $t\ge \frac12$.

Comment: Silly me, this is another question but how about each $F(s, t)$ is continuous in each coordinate. This is still weaker than $F$ being continuous and I think that avoids your example with the hole.