# Why does the homotopy definition requires more than just continuous in each coordinate?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I asked a bit earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217637/why-does-the-homotopy-definition-require-a-continuous-function/4217639#4217639) why the homotopy definition requires more than just each $f_t(s)$ being continuous. The answer was that holes can the be "skipped" by going sideways. So how about if the function $F(s, t)$ is continuous on each coordinate? That is, for every fixed $s^*$, $F(s^*, t)$ is continuous and also each $f_t(s)$ is continuous. At least visually, the homotopy classes of the few objects I know are the same under this definition than with the original.

So, what fails? Why is the other stronger notion the one that is studied?

---

As reference this is the definition I am following:

A homotopy of paths in $X$ is a family of maps $f_t: I \to X$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$, such that

- $f_t(0) = x_0$ and $f_t(1) = x_1$
- The associated map $F(s, t) = f_t(s)$ is continuous

Comment: It would seem to hinge on finding examples $F$ constant on $F(0,t)$ and $F(1,t)$ which are continuous in both variables but not entirely continuous, and seeing where they break.

Comment: An example might be $$F(s,t)=(1-s)\frac{st}{s^2+t^2}$$ with value $0$ at $(0,0).$ When $s=t\neq 0,$ the value is $(1-s)/2.$ This means that all the curves near $t=0$ have values near close to $1/2.$ That seems contrary to the idea that these curves are supposed to be “close to” the curve $f_0(s)=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Someone referred me to this [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104515/path-homotopy-and-separately-continuous-functions) which is exactly what I was looking for, so I'll close this. On a completely different note, Serre's quote in your profile is now one of my favorite quotes of all time, thanks for sharing that.

Comment: Hopefully that works https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/17225ca8-a701-4aaf-a9aa-f7237ee8bf4f